# How to programatically show New Object List from Windows Shell in my .NET application

Tags: wpf, shell, contextmenu, explorer

When you right click on your Desktop you get the shell context menu which contains "New" submenu.

Example 1:

[image: Shell New Object List]

Example 2:

[image]

I was wondering is it possible to add this feature to my C# WPF application? I would place these items in my app's context menu but I don't know how to get all those items and also how to execute selected item (eg. create new default file).

I think it would require some COM interop but I couldn't find any sample code online (not even unmanaged examples). I tried showing the whole menu context (by using gong .net shell lib) but this "New" submenu is missing from it so I figure it could be something that is not part of shell context menu but rather added by Windows Explorer dynamically. Ideally I'd like to reuse this feature from Windows Explorer even in case I'd need to show the whole context menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are called ShellNew classes.  They are just registry keys that Windows looks for.

Here's an open source project that has some helper functions for using them:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/shellnewhandler/

I'm guessing you want to retrieve a list of these from the registry and populate them in your applications?

As an example of what info you need, open regedit and go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT then look for the ".txt" keyword.  It has a "ShellNew" key and I think it also retrieves a new file name as a string resource from notepad.exe (which is optional, but gives it the "New Text Document.txt" name).  You will also notice that the default key for the .txt registry key is "txtfile".  This points to another key which describes the type of file and gives a path to its icon.

Comment: Is there a way to get this list without directly working with registry? Eg. some API or COM interop? Also what about executing commands that creates new file? This is easy for .txt files but it is tricky for other custom types such as .rar like on my system where WinRar is installed. Parsing the registry is not recommended usually and in case these keys are changed in new service pack or Win version my app will get broken. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think Windows exposes an API because most of the shell functionality is not meant to be done by applications.  It's really out of scope of what an app should be doing.  That being said, I don't think they will change the structure anytime soon since it would break compatibility with old apps.  I don't think it's changed since Win95/Win98.